# String munging in Objective-C with NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string

I have an NSAttributedString `s` and an integer `i` and I'd like a function that takes `s` and `i` and returns a new NSAttributedString that has a (stringified) `i` prepended to `s`.

It looks like some combination of `-stringWithFormat:`, `-initWithString:`, and `-insertAttributedString:` would do it but I'm having trouble piecing it together without a lot of convolution and temporary variables.

More generally, pointers to guides on making sense of NSAttributedString and NSMutableAttributedString would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for it, thanks to the friendly people on the adium developers' IRC channel.  It takes an `NSAttributedString s` and an integer `i`.

```
return [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
         initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %@", i, [s string]]]
        autorelease];
```

Answer (score 9):

I think I found another way:

```
// convert it to a mutable string
NSMutableAttributedString *newString;
newString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:old];

// create string containing the number
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

// append the number to the new string
[newString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([newString length] - 1, 0) 
                         withString:numberString];
```

I think this works because [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) says:

> **- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)aRange withString:(NSString *)aString**
>
> The new characters inherit the
>   attributes of the first replaced
>   character from aRange. Where the
>   length of aRange is 0, the new
>   characters inherit the attributes of
>   the character preceding aRange if it
>   has any, otherwise of the character
>   following aRange.

Comment: This works!  Except it should be NSMakeRange(0,0) for prepending.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, definitely time to sleep, I can't read properly anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

Pointers here: [Attributed Strings Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html)

The brief answer is use NSMutableAttributedString -- since it inherits from NSAttributedString, you can use it anywhere you'd use an (immutable) NSAttributedString.

A newly created NSMAS can slurp up the contents and attributes of an NSAS with the setAttributedString: method. You're then free to replaceCharactersInRange: or deleteCharactersInRange: or insertAttributedString: atIndex: to yours heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple attributed strings you want to put within another attributed string, you can use this Category I wrote:

You'll have to pass in NULL as the last argument to the function however, otherwise it will crash to the va_list restrictions on detecting size.

[attributedString stringWithFormat:attrFormat, attrArg1, attrArg2, NULL];

```
@implementation NSAttributedString(stringWithFormat)

+(NSAttributedString*)stringWithFormat:(NSAttributedString*)format, ...{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = (NSMutableAttributedString*)[format mutableCopy];
    NSString *mutableString = [mutableAttributedString string];

    while (true) {
        NSAttributedString *arg = va_arg(args, NSAttributedString*);
        if (!arg) {
            break;
        }
        NSRange rangeOfStringToBeReplaced = [mutableString rangeOfString:@"%@"];
        [mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:rangeOfStringToBeReplaced withAttributedString:arg];
    }

    va_end(args);

    return mutableAttributedString;
}
@end
```